# C#, how to return string as result from Async/Await Task

Tags: c#

I got Async private method that call 3rd party WCF service and in return it get string value. I have added await to the WCF call but getting error

### error

```
'string' does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible extension method accepting first argument of type string
```

### code

```
 private async Task<string> InitializeCall()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        response = await eziClient.GetTransactionsAsync(username, "", BatchNumber.ToString(), "").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        

        return response;
    }
```

not sure what I missing here?

Comment: Why do you need `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` inside `async` method?

Comment: This method shouldn't be async. Remove async and just return `eziClient.GetTransactionsAsync(username, "", BatchNumber.ToString(), "")` without any response variables

Comment: At first, it was hard for me to understand asynchronous programming. But it's really important to understand it to avoid code smell. You can read that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and that for the best practices: https://medium.com/@deep_blue_day/long-story-short-async-await-best-practices-in-net-1f39d7d84050. Avoid using .Wait() or .GetAwaiter().GetResult()!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```cs
 private async Task<string> InitializeCall()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        response = await eziClient.GetTransactionsAsync(username, "", BatchNumber.ToString(), "");
        

        return response;
    }
```

The result of `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` was a `string`, and you can't `await` a `string`.

Comment: Thanks that make sense!... that was helpful